# How to get an array as output parameter from stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, array

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAttritionData`(
 IN `supid` BIGINT, 
 IN `from_date` DATE, 
 IN `to_date` DATE, 
 OUT `attr_rate` FLOAT, 
 OUT `TERM_EMP_CNT` INT
) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
 DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
 DECLARE CNT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
 DECLARE TOT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
 DECLARE AVG_HCOUNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 

 SELECT count(employee_id) INTO TERM_EMP_CNT FROM employee 
  WHERE term_date between from_date and to_date AND app_role=1; 
 WHILE from_date<=to_date DO 
   SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) INTO CNT_EMP FROM employee 
    WHERE sup_id=supid AND doj<from_date 
    AND (term_date>from_date OR term_date='0000-00-00') AND app_role=1; 
   SET from_date=date_add(from_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
   SET i=i+1; 
   SET TOT_EMP = TOT_EMP + CNT_EMP; 
 END WHILE; 
 SET AVG_HCOUNT=(TOT_EMP/i)*365/12; 
 SET attr_rate = TERM_EMP_CNT/AVG_HCOUNT; 
END
```

I want `attr_rate` as an array, where it has 1 key and another value such as:

```
attr_rate[6-2015]=3.5
attr_rate[7-2015]=6.2
attr_rate[8-2015]=3.3
```

How do I declare an array in a MySQL stored procedure?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is not supported in stored procedure, you can use temporary table.

Try this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAttritionData`(IN `supid` BIGINT, IN `from_date` DATE, IN `to_date` DATE, OUT `attr_rate` FLOAT, OUT `TERM_EMP_CNT` INT) 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CNT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CNT_EMP_SUS INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE TOT_EMP INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1(CDATE DATE,TOTAL_EMP INTEGER, TOTAL_SUSPENDED INTEGER);
    WHILE from_date<=to_date DO
        SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) INTO CNT_EMP 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE sup_id=supid AND doj<from_date AND (term_date>from_date OR term_date='0000-00-00') AND app_role=1;
        SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) INTO CNT_EMP_SUS 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE sup_id=supid AND term_date=from_date AND app_role=1;
        INSERT INTO T1(CDATE,TOTAL_EMP,TOTAL_SUSPENDED) VALUES (from_date,CNT_EMP,CNT_EMP_SUS);
        SET from_date=date_add(from_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
    Select * from T1;
    SELECT *,count(CDATE),sum(TOTAL_EMP),SUM(TOTAL_SUSPENDED),((SUM(TOTAL_EMP)/count(CDATE))*365/12) AVG_HEAD_COUNT, (SUM(TOTAL_SUSPENDED)/((SUM(TOTAL_EMP)/count(CDATE))*365/12)) atr_rate FROM T1 group by MONTH(CDATE);

END
```

Hope your issue will be fixed.